# How to select an option from ng repeater by text in protractor?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

[image]

need to select the second option with the text "rajeshwar_9032". below is the function I wrote to click on the ng-repeat option but am unable to do so. please help.

```
this.SelectProfile = function(Profile){             
        element.all(by.repeater("profile in vm.allProfiles")).each(function (elm) {
            var desiredprofile = elm.element(by.xpath('//div/div/div/div/span[contains(text(), "'+Profile+'")]'));
            desiredprofile.click();
        });
```

where the text is passed into the argument 'Profile'

Comment: Can you remove image and add html snippet directly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `by.cssContainingText('<<>css>', '<<text>>')` rather than such an xpath to make it more stable.

refer [here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText) for more details

You can do something like below

```
 this.SelectProfile = function(Profile) {
   return element.all(by.repeater("profile in vm.allProfiles")).filter(function(elm) {
     return elm.element(by.css('.username')).getText().then(function(text) {
       return text === profile;
     })
   }).first().element(by.css('.username')).click()
 }
```

Comment: But it still says no element found in the console. Probably it might be because the code tries to click though the text is not matching. Should We use a condition to be satisfied to click?

Comment: No ..` click()` is not triggered is element if not found...it will error out at `Element Finder` itself...  can you have a `console.log(profile)` before that statement to check the value its storing

Comment: Yes, I think the error thrown by element finder while parsing through other options is displayed in the console. Is there a way to suppress the error / to throw it only after all the options are evaluated.

Comment: @RaghuRam.k .. I guess we are not thinking through your requirement clearly ... You need to filter that element which contains profile right .. my bad ..I will edit the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133355/discussion-between-raghu-ram-k-and-adityareddy).

Comment: this.SelectProfile = function(Profile) 
{
    element(by.css('.icon-person-plus')).click();
    element.all(by.id("select_profile_button")).filter(function(elm)
    { 
       return elm.element(by.css('.username')).getText().then(function(text)
       {
         return text === Profile;
    })
    }).then(function(filteredElement)
       {
          filteredElement[0].element(by.css('.username')).click();
    });       
}

Answer (score 1):

```
Finally arrived at a solution. Below code works consistently.
```

Thanks, @AdityaReddy I made minor tweaks to your suggestion and it worked great.Hope this helps.

```
this.SelectProfile = function(Profile) {
element(by.css('.icon-person-plus')).click();
element.all(by.id("select_profile_button")).filter(function(elm) {
  return elm.element(by.css('.username')).getText().then(function(text) {
   return text === Profile;
   }) 
  }).then(function(filteredElement){
              filteredElement[0].element(by.css('.username')).click();
     });
}
```